# Differences between "abundant'", "sufficient", and "enough"?

Tags: word-usage, differences

In the case I want to say there is a lot of things available and implies 'the more the better', which word should I use?

Comment: Giving us more context would be pretty useful to anyone attempting to answer your question.

Comment: Opinion:
Abundant implies much or many of something.
Sufficient implies what is necessary for something to occur. My personal experience: graduate student and then research scientist since 1988 - ecology and crop research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without you providing a clearer idea of the situation. That said, I shall take a stab at this anyway.

**Abundant** implies that there is more than enough and greater than merely sufficient.

Both **sufficient** and **enough** imply that the quantity satisfies the need and don't necessarily provide any more information.

If I had to select one of these words to answer your question I would use **abundant**. The reasoning behind this is that you want it to imply 'the more the better,' and neither 'enough' nor 'sufficient' have that connotation. In fact they have the opposite. Imagine a store owner describing his vast selection of fruits; which of these sounds better?

"We have enough variety", "Our variety is sufficient", or "We have an abundance of different fruits."

Answer (score 0):

## Plenty

I would say abundant means there's a lot and perhaps no more is needed. Plenty is somewhat less in volume but still has good conotations.

Enough and sufficient means that no more is needed. I would say that enough is the subjective of the two and sufficient is more objective